# Labels in Deployment Spec & template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In the below yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: my-nginx # Line 6
spec:             # Line 7  
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx    # line 11
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx   # Line 15
    spec:                # Line 16
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi" #128 MB
            cpu: "200m" #200 millicpu (.2 cpu or 20% of the cpu)
```

---

Deployment is given a label(`app: nginx`) at Line 6.

Deployment spec at Line 7 uses the Pod spec mentioned in Line 16

---

1. What is the purpose of `selector` field with `matchLabels`?
2. What is the purpose of `template` field with `labels`?

Comment: 1. What is the purpose of selector key with matchLabels
From the kubernetes documentation, The .spec.selector field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage. In this case, you select a label that is defined in the Pod template (app: nginx).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/



2. What is the purpose of template key with labels
If the number of pods is not equal to the replicas, then deployment will create a pod with the spec mentioned under template.

Comment: this explains the question in length https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment

Comment: @P.... How to interpret label for deployment at Line 6 vis-a-vis label for Pod at Line 15? Because they have same names

Comment: @overexchange did the answer your question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried to add comments to explain the role of labels:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: my-nginx # LABEL-A: <--this label is to manage the deployment itself. this may be used to filter the deployment based on this label. 
spec:              
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx    #LABEL-B:  <--  field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage.
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx   #LABEL-C: <--this is the label of the pod, this must be same as LABEL-B
    spec:                
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi" #128 MB
            cpu: "200m" #200 millicpu (.2 cpu or 20% of the cpu)
```

**LABEL-A:** <--this label is to manage the deployment itself. this may be used to filter the deployment based on this label. Example usage of `LABEL-A` is for deployment management, such as filtering.

```
k get deployments.apps -L app=my-nginx
```

**LABEL-B**:  <--  There must be some place where we tell replication controller to manage the pods. This field defines how the Deployment finds which Pods to manage. Based on these labels of the pod, replication controller ensure they are ready.

**LABEL-C:** <--this is the label of the pod, which LABEL-B use to monitor. this must be same as LABEL-B

Comment: Can Label A & Label C have same label(`app:my-nginx`)? what is the advantage to  have same label for both deployment & Pod?

Comment: Yes, they are typically  same. Only advantage i can think of having A and C same is easier management/filtering . However  A and C can be different.also, no use case in mind to keep them different

Comment: May I know which LABEL is used by Service yaml, meaning A or B or C?